# How to manually minify a JavascriptResult content before returning it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, minify

I have a controller that has a special method to return me a js content uppon some requests params.
Everything is working greatly, I'm simply using a method that returns a JavaScriptResult and I'm rendering a view (that has the whole js content) to a string and returning it.

Now I want to take a step further on that solution. I want that js content to be minified. I've found (on NuGet) a CrockfordJsMinifier class (part of Web Markup Minifier package) that seemed to do the job.

Problem is: It's not a complete minifier, it's only "eating" the extra spaces, line breaks, etc... It is not compressing variable or function names and stuff like that.

Hence my question: Is it possible to use the minification from the "Bundling and Minification" solution from MVC5 on a string? If so, how should I do it?

Here's a brief example of my method just to illustrate:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public JavaScriptResult GetAnonymousJS(string JSName)
    {
        //"PartialToString" just renders the view on a string.
        string result = PartialToString(PartialView("PublicViewScripts/" + JSName));

        var minifier = new CrockfordJsMinifier();
        result = minifier.Minify(result, false).MinifiedContent;

        //This result is not "really" minified (is just roughly minified)
        return JavaScript(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/). It can compress variables and function names as you want. After added the Ajaxmin.dll to your project, you can call the minifier:

```
public JavaScriptResult GetAnonymousJS(string JSName)
{
    //"PartialToString" just renders the view on a string.
    string result = PartialToString(PartialView("PublicViewScripts/" + JSName));

    var minifier = new Minifier();
    result = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(result);

    //This result is not "really" minified (is just roughly minified)
    return JavaScript(result);
}
```

http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AjaxMin%20DLL

Comment: This can be a good alternative too, if you also want to minify the html and css: http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/WebMarkupMin.Core

Comment: Ok that's it. That didi it. Thanks a lot! :)